# Porting comtypes to win32com

Tags: python, porting, win32com, comtypes, queryinterface

In a Python script I have to replace usage of comtypes by win32com and pythoncom. Essentially I have this code:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject, GetEvents

object_IXXObjManager = comtypes.client.CreateObject(xxxId)
connection_IXXObjManager = GetEvents(object_IXXObjManager, IXXObjManagerEventHandler())

object_IXXObjCommunications = object_IXXObjManager.QueryInterface(comtypes.gen.XXOBJLib.IXXObjCommunications)
connection_IXXObjCommunications = GetEvents(object_IXXObjCommunications, IXXObjCommunicationEventHandler(), interface=comtypes.gen.XXOBJLib.IXXObjCommunicationsEvents)
```

and the target is to get similar functionality using win32com. In my understanding the event handler classes will require no changes.
First part was easy:

```
import win32com.client
object_IXXObjManager = win32com.client.Dispatch(xxxId)
event_IXXObjManager = win32com.client.WithEvents(object_IXXObjManager, IXXObjManagerEventHandler)
```

However, I got stuck when trying to map an event handler to a object from queried interface.

```
object_IXXObjManager._oleobj_.QueryInterface( ??? )
```

Could you help me? I do have general sw development experience, however limited COM knowledge.

Comment: I ported the initial part of the code: `object_IXXObjManager = win32com.client.Dispatch(xxxId)
event_IXXObjManager = win32com.client.WithEvents(object_IXXObjManager, IXXObjManagerEventHandler)` but I guess I have to add also something like `object_IXXObjManager._oleobj_.QueryInterface( ??? )` which I do not know exactly how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement for

```
object_IXXObjCommunications = object_IXXObjManager.QueryInterface(comtypes.gen.XXOBJLib.IXXObjCommunications)
```

can be like this:

```
iface = object_XXObjManager._oleobj_.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
iface_Communications = win32com.client.CastTo(iface,"XXObjCommunications")
connection_XXObjCommunications = win32com.client.Dispatch(iface_Communications)
```

Comment: I noticed that there are different interfaces between python and com: `comtypes`, `pythoncom` and `win32com`. I wonder if you know the differences between the different interfaces and why you would one over the other?